Conda - Conflict Installing Dependencies from environment.yml in MEDFAIR Project
I'm trying to set up the MEDFAIR project from GitHub. When I run conda env create -f environment.yml, I encounter the following error:
ERROR: Cannot install -r /path/to/condaenv.requirements.txt (line 132) and tornado==4.5.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

I've tried manually editing the environment.yml file and installing tornado separately, but the issue persists. Here’s my environment.yml snippet:
name: medfair
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - numpy=1.19.2
  - pandas=1.1.3
  - scikit-learn=0.23.2
  - matplotlib=3.3.2
  - seaborn=0.11.0
  - tornado=4.5.3  # This line causes conflict
  # Other dependencies

I tried to use:
pip install tornado

its installed but I got this error again
I removed tornado from enviroments.yml this time I got numpy conflic error!
Any suggestions on how to resolve this conflict?

What are the other dependencies? That is a very unusual error message to me if all you're doing is conda operations.
